# Importing data from RDBMS using SQOOP

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to import data from SQL server database to Hive. Basically I am importing the whole database(except some tables) to Hive. Here I have some questions which I couldn't get answer from anywhere.

1. Can we use "--hive-import" with import-all-tables and --exclude-tables. ? If not, once I load all the tables into hfds, how do I use create external table option for building metadata for all the tables?
2. Can we specify the hive database name anywhere in sqoop import command. ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your questions.

1. No. 
   As mentioned in the Apache document: "The --exclude-tables argument is for +sqoop-import-all-tables only". See below document from Apache (Search for the quote".
   https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax.

2.Yes. Here is an example.

```
import-all-tables  --connect ${connectString} --username ${username} -- password ${password}  --hive-home /opt/hive  --hive-database ${database} -- verbose --hive-import --hive-drop-import-delims -m 1
```

Comment: Thanks. So in that case, once I load tables to hdfs, how to I create external table for multiple files already in hdfs?

Comment: I think you can use import-all-tables with "--exclude-tables", specify the "--hive-database". All the tables will be created automatically in Hive. If you do not use "--hive-import", you have to create external tables manually.

Answer (score 0):

For importing data to external hive table from RDBMS you need to follow

1) Create  external hive table.(Have to create all tables).
2) Import data using Sqoop.(This can be done using shell script)

Prepare a inputfile which has list of DBNAME.TABLENAME.
The shell script will have this file as input, iterate line by line and execute sqoop statement for each line.

```
while read line;
do

    DBNAME=`echo $line | cut -d'.' -f1` 
    tableName=`echo $line | cut -d'.' -f2`


    sqoop import -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=$QUEUE_NAME --connect '$JDBC_URL;databaseName=$DBNAME;username=$USERNAME;password=$PASSWORD' --table $tableName  --target-dir $HIVE_EXTERNAL_TABLE_PATH/$tableName  --fields-terminated-by '\001'  -m 1 


done<inputFile
```